# How do I make an Observable Interval start immediately without a delay?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I want my observable to fire immediately, and again every second. [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) will not fire immediately. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft) which suggested using `startWith`, which DOES fire immediately, but I then get a duplicate first entry.

```js
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(4).startWith(0).subscribe(onNext);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Cl5DQ7znJRDe0VTv0Ux5?p=preview

How can I make interval fire immediately, but not duplicate the first entry?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Before RxJs 6:

`Observable.timer(0, 1000)` will start immediately.

RxJs 6+

```js
import {timer} from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
timer(0, 1000).subscribe(() => { ... });
```

Comment: if I want the sequence to repeat, `0` prints immediately after `3` without a delay in-between. Is there a way to fix that? https://plnkr.co/edit/Muw5d4b8slOA3CcW4vXC?p=preview

Comment: try to do let obs$ = 
    Rx.Observable.concat(
       Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).timestamp().take(4),
       Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).timestamp().take(4)
    )
    .repeat(); but i am not sure.

Comment: That helped! https://plnkr.co/edit/8KAcv2hgMLYMREzs4xvN?p=preview  Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

> RxJs 6. **Note: With this solution, `0` value will be emitted twice** (one time immediately by `startWith`, and one time by `interval` stream after the first "tick", so if you care about the value emitted, you could consider startWith(-1) instead of startWith(0)

```js
interval(100).pipe(startWith(0)).subscribe(() => { //your code });
```

or with timer:

```js
import {timer} from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
timer(0, 100).subscribe(() => {

    });
```

Comment: for RxJs 6+
interval(100).pipe(startWith(0)).subscribe(() => {
//your code 
});

Comment: Regarding RxJs 6: You still need to import startWith (`import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';`)

Comment: If I use startWith, my interval starts at the parameter value of startWith but on the 2nd iteration, goes back to zero

IE - .startWith(6) gives a sequence of 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: yes, if you want 0,1,.. then timer is better. Startwith can be nice if you want to start with null or with -1 or something.

Answer (score 9):

With RxJava2, there's no issue with duplicated first entry and this code is working fine:

```js
io.reactivex.Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .startWith(0L)
        .subscribe(aLong -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "test");    // do whatever you want
    });
```

Note you need to pass `Long` in startWith, so `0L`.

Answer (score 3):

### RxJava 2

If you want to generate a sequence `[0, N]` with each value delayed by **D** seconds, use the following overload:

```java
Observable<Long> interval(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

> **initialDelay** - the initial delay time to wait before emitting the first value of 0L

```kotlin
Observable.interval(0, D, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(N+1)
```

You can also try to use `startWith(0L)` but it will generate sequence like: `{0, 0, 1, 2...}`

I believe something like that will do the job too:

```kotlin
Observable.range(0, N).delayEach(D, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```