# What is the most concise way to emit consecutive values every interval starting immediately using system.reactive?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Consider the following code in Linqpad:

```
DateTime.Now.Dump();
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    //.Select(n => n + 1)
    //.StartWith(0)
    .Do(n => $"{DateTime.Now} {n}".Dump())
    .Wait();
```

It outputs:

```
1/22/2019 12:23:57 PM
1/22/2019 12:24:00 PM 0
1/22/2019 12:24:03 PM 1
```

Notice that the first element is observed 3 seconds later. I want it to be right away, which is on subscription, I suppose. My solution is:

```
DateTime.Now.Dump();
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .Select(n => n + 1)
    .StartWith(0)
    .Do(n => $"{DateTime.Now} {n}".Dump())
    .Wait();
```

Which produces:

```
1/22/2019 12:26:10 PM
1/22/2019 12:26:10 PM 0
1/22/2019 12:26:13 PM 1
1/22/2019 12:26:16 PM 2
```

Note the first element is observed right away.

I was wondering if there is a more concise way to achieve this.

Comment: what do you mean by immedietally? Upon creation or subscription?

Comment: Hmm. Subscription I guess.

Comment: Why is it a duplicate? I do not need a hot observable. Let me edit the post.

Comment: then use `Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165893/how-do-i-make-an-observable-interval-start-immediately-without-a-delay

Comment: Now I can see it is a duplicate. Thank you.