# Get RxJS Observable to return initial data immediately and then repeat every X seconds afterwards?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Below is a code sample that gives me results every **30 seconds**, however, when a component subscribes to the service, **it also has to wait 30 seconds** for the initial set of data:

```
getTasks(query: string): Observable<any> {
  return this._http.get(this._ripcord + '/tasks' + query, this.getHttpOptions())
    .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
    .delay(30000)
    .repeat()
    .do(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I looked at a [similar issue on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft) but this solution doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know what operator I can use, in combination, to retrieve the initial data immediately on subscribe?

Comment: The solution in that question should work here.  What was wrong with it?

Comment: The subscription returns an integer instead of the object!

Comment: You gotta use `flatMap` or something similar (putting your original request inside the map), as several of the answers show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you all** for your responses as they helped me create my own solutions!

```
getTasks(query: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable
    .timer(0, 30000)
    .switchMap(() =>
      this._http.get(this._ripcord + '/tasks' + query, this.getHttpOptions())
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

OR

```
getTasks(query: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable
    .interval(30000)
    .startWith(0)
    .switchMap(() =>
      this._http.get(this._ripcord + '/tasks' + query, this.getHttpOptions())
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

OR

```
getTasks(query: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable
    .timer(0, 30000)
    .switchMap(() =>
      this._http.get(this._ripcord + '/tasks' + query, this.getHttpOptions())
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())

    )
    .do(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I realized I needed to utilize **switchMap** as map was returning an Observable in the subscription to the Http service GET response of the getTAsks endpoint. You can put the DO and the CATCH operators optionally on the switchMap instead of the map operator.

Answer (score 0):

interval.startWith (as referenced in the solution that you point to) is indeed the answer.

I suspect that what you really want is something like:

```
Observable
  .interval(30000)
  .startWith(0)
  .map(event =>
    this._http.get(this._ripcord + '/tasks' + query, this.getHttpOptions())
  )
  .do(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [timer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer). With timer you can specify when should emission start. Following sample emits first value immediately then it takes 5 secs to emit subsequent values.

```
var sourceTimer = Rx.Observable
        .timer(0, 5000)
        .timeInterval()
        .take(10);

var subscriptionTimer = sourceTimer.subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ' + JSON.stringify(x));
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        });
```

**Output:**

```
Next: {"value":0,"interval":4}
Next: {"value":1,"interval":5004}
Next: {"value":2,"interval":5000}
```

[Interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) & [startWith](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) also work, immediately emits the value zero which you provided as parameter to startWith then emits subsequent values in provided  interval.

```
  var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval( 5000 /* ms */)
    .startWith(0)
    .timeInterval()
    .take(10);

 var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + JSON.stringify(x));
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

**Output:**

```
Next: {"value":0,"interval":1}
Next: {"value":0,"interval":5003}
Next: {"value":1,"interval":5000}

Next: {"value":7,"interval":5000}
Next: {"value":8,"interval":5001}
```

Comment: Timer has been deprecated in favor of interval

Comment: I noticed that you're also using the timeInterval operator. What's the purpose of having both timer (interval) and timeInterval?

Comment: Also I didn't see where timer was **deprecated**.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the observable sequence going when the http request returns an error catch the error when making the request and return an empty observable.

```
  getTasks(query: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable
      .interval(30000)
      .startWith(0)
      .switchMap(event => {
        this._http
          .get(this._ripcord + '/tasks' + query, this.getHttpOptions())
          .catch(error => Observable.empty());
      })
      .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Otherwise the sequence will stop on the first error.

Comment: This option to me isn't clear to understand and it crashes my application with **TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined**

Comment: @AndrewLobban you would have to be check for null being emitted and handle that. The important bit is that only having a catch on the end of the observable chain will mean that if the _http.get fails the observable will stop. By handling the error and then returning an observable it will keep on making the request every 30 seconds,

Comment: Thanks! I did realize however the map wasn't returning my data object, but another observable, so I needed to merge the observables with switchMap. Hence the DO operator wouldn't have data to log. So if you see my solution, I remedied that.

Comment: @AndrewLobban You're right sorry about that. I should have used switchMap not map. I've updated the answer. You can do the map after the switchMap and check is the response is null there