# Call function immediately and every X seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

Using Angular 7 how to call function immediately and every X seconds?
This is my function in service: (just as an example)

```
checkData(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get('')
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                let result;
                result = {
                    packageNumber: this.packageNumber,
                };
                return result;
            })
        );
}
```

And in my component I tried something like this:

```
private killTrigger: Subject<void> = new Subject();
private fetchData$: Observable<string> = this.packageService.checkData();

private refreshInterval$: Observable<string> = timer(0, 1000)
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.killTrigger),
        switchMap(() => this.fetchData$),
        catchError(error => of('Error'))
    );
```

How to make it work?

Comment: I think you're looking for [interval](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval)

Comment: @WillCain can it be used immediately?

Comment: `timer(0, 1000)` already does that. Did you subscribe?

Comment: `.interval(5000).startWith(0);` if I recall https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft

Comment: @martin so which approach is better? timer or interval

Comment: @ChrisK. If want to start emit without the initial delay use `timer`

Comment: @martin could you write an answer with an example of subscribe?

Comment: Yeah I didn't know timer but that looks better. Subscription is key. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe

Comment: `timer(0, 1000).pipe(...).subscribe(...)`

Comment: @martin but then it got called only once

Comment: @martin ok it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to it to launch it. Best way is to:

```typescript
// class def
private subscription: Subscription;
// in NgOnInit
this.subscription = this.refreshInterval$.subscribe(noop)
// in NgOnDestroy
this.subscription.unsubscribe(); // avoid memory leaks
```

And to actually fire your `fetchData$`, you can replace your `switchMap` call by:

```
map(() => this.fetchData$.subscribe(noop),
```

If you don't subscribe to the observable, it never gets fired. Don't see why you would need `switchMap` here.