# Angular 6 run code every 5 seconds but it emits for 1st time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, intervals

I want to run my code as soon as it gets into my component and repeat the logic every 5 seconds

Here is my code, I used the interval of rxjs

```
ngOnInit() {
  const ticker = interval(5000);
  ticker.subscribe(() => {
    this.calculateTime();
  });
}
```

But the issue here is that for the code runs

```
1st time at 5s 
2nd time at 10s
```

But I want it to run as

```
1st time at 0s 
2nd time at 5s
3rs time at 10s
```

This is how I tacked:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const ticker = interval(5000);
  this.calculateTime();
  ticker.subscribe(() => {
    this.calculateTime();
  });
}
```

If you notice I called `this.calculateTime();` twice once before ticker and 2nd inside ticker.

> Is there a better solution using `interval` ? If not may be an alternative to `interval`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an observable to return data immediately and every 5 seconds thereafter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `timer`. It does the same as `interval` but adds the functionality you need: controlling the first emission.

```
ngOnInit() {
  const ticker = timer(0, 5000);
  ticker.subscribe(() => {
    this.calculateTime();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
// ....
const ticker = interval(5000).pipe(
     startWith(0)
);
```

Comment: [ts] Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'. [2339]

Comment: Which version of RxJS are you using?

Comment: I am using Rxjs 6.3.3

Comment: See the updated answer, however the accepted answer is a better approach.

Comment: still same isse

Comment: Did you import the `startWith` operator?

Comment: Yes, I did so. I copied your code and replaced it with my code.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, inside the`pipe()` it should be `startWith(0)`, without a dot before it.