# How can I make Observable.interval() fire immediately in RxJava?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I want to create an observable that emits values every 5 seconds (0s, 5s, 10s, etc) and when I used `Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` there's 5 seconds delay before emitting the very first event and when I googled and tried to use `Observable.timer` I was confused by its `Scheduler scheduler` parameter.

My current workaround (after I found the answers to some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft) question) is to add `.startsWith(0L)`:

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startsWith(0L)
```

Is there an operator that accepts delay (or takes 0 by default) and where I can specify an interval?

Comment: `Observable.interval()` emits items from `0` and it results in `0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2...`. Besides that, it looks a bit hacky.

Comment: [I just found this method. Seems like it's what you need.](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#interval-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)